# Why is the sequence of bookmark.sty and showlabel.sty important?

Tags: bookmarks, showlabels

The MWE does not show labels. However when changing the \usepackage{bookmark} in front of \usepackage{showlabels}, it does. I have looked through all the questions about showlabels and did not find an answer.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[outer]{showlabels}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
    test\label{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated but better don't use ucs and utf8x, but only utf8 (or in a current latex don't load inputenc at all, as utf8 is the default anyway). ucs is not compatible with everything.

Comment: Unfortunately, this comes from the start widget of texstudio, which I didnot change here for the MWE.

Comment: I can't confirm this, I just checked and my texstudio (version 3.0.1) doesn't add ucs if I use a template.

Comment: I checked with texstudio 3.0.1: Only if utf8x is selected, then ucs is shown as a package.

Comment: I have no idea how to select utf8x in texstudio, but if you did it, you should better deselect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual says:

> In version 1.3e, the package became compatible with the {hyperref} package in particular, and in general with other packages which themselves modify the \label command. This will work, however, only if the {showlabels} package is loaded after other packages which do this.

And `bookmark` is one of those packages (UPDATE: since `bookmark` loads `hyperref`, as Heiko kindly explained in the comments)

Comment: Package `bookmark` does not mess with `\label`, it only deals with PDF bookmark stuff. But it loads package `hyperref`.

Comment: Makes (more) sense, thanks